# Check If post id exist in custom post type , outside of loop

Tags: post-type

How can I search in database if id exist in a post type?. I want to search `$id=123` in post type 'movies' like this, is this the correct way to do it?

```
   $content = get_posts('post_type=movies&id=$id');

    if ($content)
            echo "post id exist";

        else
            echo "post id doesn't exist";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
echo 'movie' === get_post_type( 123 ) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

But if you need to check it many times in your theme, you might consider defining your own helper function:

```
if( ! function_exists( 'is_movie' ) )
{
    function is_movie( $mixed = null )
    {
        return 'movie' === get_post_type( $mixed );
    }
}
```

It might return true when `$mixed` is empty, `\WP_Post` object or a post ID.

So if you want to know if there exists a *movie* with ID `123`:

```
echo is_movie( 123 ) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

or just `is_move()` within the loop, to check the current post ID.

If you only need to check if the ID `123` exists, then just use `get_post()`.

For example:

```
echo is_null( get_post( 123 ) ) ? 'No' : 'Yes';
```